# ¿Cómo afecta el uso múltiple de la función setInterval?

Tags: javascript

Si programamos un juego en JavaScript, empleando la etiqueta `<canvas>`, y tengo tres intervalos, ¿el hecho de que haya tres intervalos ejecutándose puede afectar notablemente al rendimiento del juego? Me refiero a que este pueda pararse, o que se ejecuten más recursos de los necesarios. Tengo en cuenta que todos los cálculos en JavaScript se realizan a gran velocidad.

```js
setInterval(actualizarLienzo, 20);
setInterval(crearEnemigos, 700);
setInterval(crearNaves, 500);
```

Answer (score 5):

La llamada a la función definida en `setInterval` no es algo especialmente costoso, no debería ser un problema en general, pero su ejecución no estará sincronizada con el refresco de la pantalla y puede crear efectos visuales indeseados, así que no es recomendable usarla para lanzar tu función `actualizarLienzo`. Para este caso en especial es recomendable usar `requestAnimationFrame`, cuyo funcionamiento es similar a setTimeout (hay que definir cada llamada):

```javascript
function mainLoop(){
  //procesando los cambios...
  window.requestAnimationFrame( mainLoop ); //preparamos la siguiente ejecución
}
```

Para el resto de casos: En los juegos o experiencias interactivas generalmente no se usa setInterval, lo que se hace es guardar el momento de la última ejecución (`window.performance.now()`, por ejemplo) y comprobar dentro del ciclo principal si debemos ejecutar el resto de funciones:

```javascript
let times = {
  crearEnemigos: 0,
  crearNaves: 0,
}

function mainLoop(){

  if (tocaCrearEnemigos()) { //comprueba si ha pasado el tiempo necesario
    crearEnemigos();
  }
  actualizarLienzo()
  window.requestAnimationFrame( mainLoop ); 
}
```

En esta [respuesta de SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38709924/1919228) puedes ver un ejemplo funcionando en el que puedes usar rAF (requestAnimationFrame) o setTimeout para refrescar un canvas y se nota mucho la diferencia entre un método y otro.

Comment: Qué interesante, no conocía `requestAnimationFrame`.